# How do you add a general label to facets in ggplot2?

Tags: r, label, facet, ggplot2

I often have numeric values for faceting.
I wish to provide sufficient information to interpret these faceting values in a supplemental title, similar to the axis titles.
The labeller options repeat much unnecessary text and are unusable for longer variable titles.

Any suggestions?

The default:

```
test<-data.frame(x=1:20, y=21:40, facet.a=rep(c(1,2),10), facet.b=rep(c(1,2), each=20))
qplot(data=test, x=x, y=y, facets=facet.b~facet.a)
```

[image]

What I would love:

[image]

The best I can do in ggplot:

```
qplot(data=test, x=x, y=y)+facet_grid(facet.b~facet.a, labeller=label_both)
```

[image]

As indicated by @Hendy, similar to:
[add a secondary y axis to ggplot2 plots - make it perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096671/add-a-secondary-y-axis-to-ggplot2-plots-make-it-perfect)

Comment: Holy cow. I was *just* looking for this, found this via google... and now see it was asked a minute ago. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096671/add-a-secondary-y-axis-to-ggplot2-plots-make-it-perfect) seems to be asking the same thing based on his comment, despite the title that might imply otherwise. Great mockups to illustrate. This is exactly my problem -- it'd be nice if I didn't have to explain my numerical facet categories. The graph should speak for itself with a simple label explaining what the faceting variables were.

Comment: I asked a [similar question in the past.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7603949/707145)

Comment: I inquired with Winston Chang (don't know his SO handle), one of the main ggplot developers, via email. He doesn't think this is currently an option but might consider adding it. He suggested I add an issue on github, [so I did](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/612)

Comment: Looks like this came up on the mailing list and Winston let me know. He created a branch with a general implementation of this for top labels. See the thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2-dev/_gpWsOWrSDk). @hadley: you are correct. I have no idea how hard it is to do in general. If this never happens... my gratitude for ggplot still prevails :)

Comment: At some point I stop trying to wrangle R/ggplot2 and make some desired modifications using an image editor.

Comment: I second what Andy said. Save the plot in SVG format, and pop the result into a vector editor, such as Inkscape. You can edit the plot perfectly. Is this an option in your case?

Comment: any update on best practice here?

Comment: I know this is old, but for those still looking for an answer; have a look at the answer I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316169/nested-facets-in-ggplot2-spanning-groups/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As the latest `ggplot2` uses `gtable` internally, it is quite easy to modify a figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- data.frame(x=1:20, y=21:40, 
                   facet.a=rep(c(1,2),10), 
                   facet.b=rep(c(1,2), each=20))
p <- qplot(data=test, x=x, y=y, facets=facet.b~facet.a)

# get gtable object
z <- ggplotGrob(p)

library(grid)
library(gtable)
# add label for right strip
z <- gtable_add_cols(z, unit(z$widths[[7]], 'cm'), 7)
z <- gtable_add_grob(z, 
                     list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = gray(0.5))),
                          textGrob("Variable 1", rot = -90, gp = gpar(col = gray(1)))),
                     4, 8, 6, name = paste(runif(2)))

# add label for top strip
z <- gtable_add_rows(z, unit(z$heights[[3]], 'cm'), 2)
z <- gtable_add_grob(z, 
                     list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = gray(0.5))),
                          textGrob("Variable 2", gp = gpar(col = gray(1)))),
                     3, 4, 3, 6, name = paste(runif(2)))

# add margins
z <- gtable_add_cols(z, unit(1/8, "line"), 7)
z <- gtable_add_rows(z, unit(1/8, "line"), 3)

# draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(z)
```

[image]

Of course, you can write a function that automatically add the strip labels. A future version of `ggplot2` may have this functionality; not sure though.

Comment: --   I am wondering if this is still the cleanest approach, as of version 0.9.3.1.   I don't see something that looks like "this fuctionality" in latest documentation http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/

Comment: Version 0.9.3.1 provides `ggplotGrob()` that is same as `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build())`. I think this is still the best way.

Comment: This approach overwrites the legend when there is one. I wonder if there is a way to prevent this.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this solution is no more valid as some functions are now deprecated.

Comment: @Remi.b try it now

Comment: Oh yes, I figured out but missed the opportunity to make the edit you did. I have used this "kind of code" in a number of presentation already. It is very handy. Thanks it works fine!

Comment: This is not working with ggplot2 3.2.1 and R 3.6.1. No error message but I don't get the labels on the resulting plot.

Comment: It would be really helpful to have more explanation for what the code is doing. For example, I have no idea what `z$widths[[7]]` is the width of. In my application, its value is 1null, and I have no idea how adding a column with a null width helps. Oddly, that is not what that `gtable_add_cols` seems to do, as it does add space to the right for some reason.

Answer (score 25):

The secondary axis is now an option: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

```r
# Basic faceted plot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs ~ am)
    
    # Create a simple secondary axis for the facets (use the appropriate scale_x function)
p + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name = "SECOND Y AXIS", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name = "SECOND X AXIS", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image: Plot output]

Comment: This is awesome since there is no need for another package than ggplot2. Thanks!

Comment: MVP here giving an awesome answer 9 years after the original question was asked. thanks for it!!

Comment: Seems like this will only work for continuous data though

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way to do it, but you can :

```
fac1 = factor(rep(c('a','b'),10))
fac2 = factor(rep(c('a','b'),10))
data = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, fac1=fac1, fac2=fac2)
p = ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) + ggplot2::geom_point() + 
facet_grid(fac1~fac2)
p + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5,1.5,0.2,0.2), "cm"))
grid::grid.text(unit(0.98,"npc"),0.5,label = 'label ar right', rot = 270) # right
grid::grid.text(unit(0.5,"npc"),unit(.98,'npc'),label = 'label at top', rot = 0)   # top
```

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for replying to this decade old question, but wanted to put it out there that you can use `ggh4x::facet_nested()` to put spanning strips in a plot. Downside is that you'd need an extra package, upside is that you don't need to mess about with the gtables.

```r
# install.packages("ggh4x")
library(ggplot2)

test<-data.frame(x=1:20, y=21:40, facet.a=rep(c(1,2),10), facet.b=rep(c(1,2), each=20))

ggplot(test, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggh4x::facet_nested("Facet B" + facet.b ~ "Facet A" + facet.a)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Disclaimer: I wrote ggh4x.

Comment: Hi. I am trying to use ggh4x but I get an error. There is no package called 'ggh4x'.

Comment: @KevinSantos have you tried `install.packages("ggh4x")` first?

Comment: That was my error. But now, in every facet add all options. I mean, in facet A appears all options for A and B, in facet B appears all options for A and B.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer deviates from the desired solution. If your use-case is different than in the question above, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @teunbrand, thank you very much for writing such a useful package. I am just wondering the behavior in you answer is not documented, and would you like to add some docs to explain a little about it?

Comment: @LiangZhang what behaviour in particular couldn't you find back in the documentation?

Comment: @teunbrand I meant that I didn't find documentation of the syntax `"Facet B" + facet.b ~ "Facet A" + facet.a` in `facet_nested()`.

Comment: Ah right. That isn't syntax specific to `facet_nested()`, you can do the same with `facet_grid()` and `facet_wrap()`. As long as it is extending ggplot2's behaviour, I didn't feel I had to document this specifically.

Comment: I understand it now. The `+` here is just add another column with given string in place for view.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the method outlined by kohske, you can add a border to the boxes added by changing

```
col=NA
```

to

```
col=gray(0.5), linetype=1
```

Also, change

```
fill=gray(0.5)
```

for

```
fill=grey(0.8)
```

and

```
gp=gpar(col=gray(1))
```

to

```
gp=gpar(col=gray(0))
```

If you want the new bars to match the facet labels

ie

```
z <- gtable_add_grob(z, 
      list(rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = gray(0.5), linetype=1, fill = gray(0.8))),
      textGrob("Variable 1", rot = -90, gp = gpar(col = gray(0)))),
      4, 8, 6, name = paste(runif(2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution is to use `gridExtra`.  You can put in text or you can use calls to `grid.text` to get some formatting options.

```
library(ggplot2)
# Basic faceted plot

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs ~ am)

grid.arrange(p,top='Top Label', right='Right Label')
```

[image]