# ggplot2: Nested variables in facet_grid

Tags: r, graph, graphics, ggplot2, facet

```
require(ggplot2)

x = c(rnorm(30,3,3),rnorm(30,3,3),rnorm(30,1.5,0.2),rnorm(30,1.5,5))
y = x + rnorm(length(x))
d = data.frame(x=x, y=y, Country = rep(c("Australia", "Iran"),each=60), Environment = rep(rep(c("Forest", "Desert"),each=30),2))

ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~Country+Environment)
```

[image]

I would like the two possible values of the variable `Country` (`Australia` and `Iran`) to be written only twice at the top of the graph and have longer horizontal grey bars in order to encompass the two possible values of the nested variable `Environment`. Is it feasible?

---

Of course one could do things like

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(Country~Environment)
```

or

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y, colour=Environment)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(Country~.)
```

but it is not what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I'm not immediate aware of any technique more recent than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11353287/324364).

Comment: You can kind of tell Hadley wants you to use `facet_grid(Country~Environment)`.

Comment: @joran. Thank you I marked my question as a duplicate