# How does `ggplotGrob` work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[docs.ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/ggplotGrob.html) currently offers very little documentation for the function `ggplotGrob`. The [EPFL website](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/ggplot2/html/ggplotGrob-1l.html) is a little bit more informative but it is still not very helpful.

Can you please provide a short tutorial on what one can do with the function `ggplotGrob`?

Comment: My final goal is to reproduce the graph presented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353287/how-do-you-add-a-general-label-to-facets-in-ggplot2/12660057#12660057). The code in the answer is using functions that are deprecated.

Comment: ggplot2 has far more nuanced facet labeling options now. pls see if they can meet your needs first before grobbing.

Comment: btw the "EPFL website" is just a very old version of the documentation, before ggplotGrob was removed and later re-introduced in another form, IIRC.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ggplotGrob` is the same as `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))`; it's just a convenience function to save some typing.

The end goal is to convert the ggplot object, which is essentially a list describing how to build the plot, into a gtable, which is a grid graphical object (grob) that can be drawn on a device. So if what you're after is altering the output of `ggplotGrob` to change the layout or add graphical components to it, you should look into the gtable package.