# Axis labels for facet_grid of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can someone identify that how can I place top and right axis labels for ggplot while using facet_grid?

Consider following code which is resulting plot given below. I want to place axis label "Days" and "Gender" for top and right axis. The one alternative is using `labeller` or 'levels` but it will change the top labels instead of having axis labels.

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(tips, aes(total_bill, tip)) + 
  facet_grid(sex ~ day) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("Total Bill") + 
  ylab("Tip")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you easily can... But `ggtitle` could be used for the top label.

Comment: it' not perfect but you could try: b being the name of your plot; library(cowplot); ggdraw(b) +   theme(plot.margin=unit(c(3,3,3,3),"mm")) + draw_label("Day", x = 0.5, y = 1, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 14, fontface = 'bold') + draw_label("Gender", x = 1, y = 0.5, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 14, fontface = 'bold', angle = 270)

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941197/overall-label-for-facets/37292665#37292665)?