# Label for all facets in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the chart below, each separate facet is labeled, and there is a separate label on the left for the Y-axis. I'd like to make the label "Metrics" appear on top of the facet labels, as a single label joining all of the individual labels. I know about things like `label_both` but this does not address the issue.

[image]

Essentially, I would like something like this connecting each facet:
[image]

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.csv('Lab3.csv')
df$SVO <- factor(df$SVO,
                 levels=c("S","V","O"))
long.df <- df %>% gather(Metric, Value, Duration:Intensity)

ggplot(long.df, aes(x=Focus, y=Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=Focus)) +
  facet_grid(Metric ~ SVO, scales='free_y') +
  labs(y="Metrics")
```

Comment: How about `+ ggtitle(subtitle="Metrics") + theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5))`.

Comment: I get the error "  argument "label" is missing, with no default
"

Comment: Got it to work. It just adds a subtitle

Comment: It's not quite clear. Does the subtitle do what you want, or not? If not, can you explain what you mean by "on top of the facet labels" ?

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. I added a picture.

Comment: Something like this: [overall-label-for-facets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941197/overall-label-for-facets/37292665#37292665)

Comment: Yep! That'll do it. I'll see myself out.