# Nested facets in ggplot2 spanning groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I encountered a situation in which I want to create a plot that was facetted by three grouping variables. To do so, I would simply use `facet_grid(f1 ~ f2 + f3)`, but the issue here is that the labels for f2 would be redundant, and it would be much better to have them span the facets for f3 nested within f2.

MWE:

```
library('tibble')
library('ggplot2')
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~f1, ~f2, ~f3,
  0.5, 0.5, "a", "a", "a",
  0.5, 0.5, "b", "a", "a",
  0.5, 0.5, "a", "b", "a",
  0.5, 0.5, "b", "b", "a",
  0.5, 0.5, "a", "a", "b",
  0.5, 0.5, "b", "a", "b",
  0.5, 0.5, "a", "b", "b",
  0.5, 0.5, "b", "b", "b"
)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(f1 ~ f2 + f3)
```

[image: MWE of nested facet plot]

Again, I'm looking to combine the labels for f2 so that they are not so redundant.

Edit: This is different from other questions in that it asks how to use the existing groupings to modify a facet as opposed to adding a new one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer to this lies within the `grid` and `gtable` packages. Everything in the plot is laid out in a particular order and you can find where everything is if you dig a little.

```
library('gtable')
library('grid')
library('magrittr') # for the %>% that I love so well

# First get the grob
z <- ggplotGrob(p)
```

The ultimate goal of this operation is to overlay the top facet label, but the trick is that both of these facets exist on the same row in the grid space. They are a table within a table (look at the rows with the name "strip", also take note of the `zeroGrob`; these will be useful later):

```
z
## TableGrob (13 x 14) "layout": 34 grobs
##     z         cells       name                                   grob
## 1   0 ( 1-13, 1-14) background        rect[plot.background..rect.522]
## 2   1 ( 7- 7, 4- 4)  panel-1-1               gTree[panel-1.gTree.292]

                                    ...

## 20  3 ( 7- 7,12-12)   axis-r-1                         zeroGrob[NULL]
## 21  3 ( 9- 9,12-12)   axis-r-2                         zeroGrob[NULL]
## 22  2 ( 6- 6, 4- 4)  strip-t-1                          gtable[strip]
## 23  2 ( 6- 6, 6- 6)  strip-t-2                          gtable[strip]
## 24  2 ( 6- 6, 8- 8)  strip-t-3                          gtable[strip]
## 25  2 ( 6- 6,10-10)  strip-t-4                          gtable[strip]
## 26  2 ( 7- 7,11-11)  strip-r-1                          gtable[strip]
## 27  2 ( 9- 9,11-11)  strip-r-2                          gtable[strip]

                                    ...

## 32  8 ( 3- 3, 4-10)   subtitle  zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.519]
## 33  9 ( 2- 2, 4-10)      title     zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.518]
## 34 10 (12-12, 4-10)    caption   zeroGrob[plot.caption..zeroGrob.520]
```

If you zoom in to the first strip, you can see the nested structure:

```
z$grob[[22]]
## TableGrob (2 x 1) "strip": 2 grobs
##   z     cells  name                                 grob
## 1 1 (1-1,1-1) strip absoluteGrob[strip.absoluteGrob.451]
## 2 2 (2-2,1-1) strip absoluteGrob[strip.absoluteGrob.475]
```

For each grob, we have an object that lists the order in which it's plotted (**z**), the position in the grid (**cells**), a label (**name**), and a geometry (**grob**).

Since we can create gtables within gtables, we are going to use this to plot over our original plot. First, we need to find the positions in the plot that need replacing.

```
# Find the location of the strips in the main plot
locations <- grep("strip-t", z$layout$name)

# Filter out the strips (trim = FALSE is important here for positions relative to the main plot)
strip <- gtable_filter(z, "strip-t", trim = FALSE)

# Gathering our positions for the main plot
top <- strip$layout$t[1]
l   <- strip$layout$l[c(1, 3)]
r   <- strip$layout$r[c(2, 4)]
```

Once we have the positions, we need to create a replacement table. We can do this with a matrix of lists (yes, it's weird. Just roll with it). This matrix needs to have three columns and two rows in our case because of the two facets and the gap between them. Since we are just going to replace data in the matrix later, we're going to create one with `zeroGrob`s:

```
mat   <- matrix(vector("list", length = 6), nrow = 2)
mat[] <- list(zeroGrob())

# The separator for the facets has zero width
res <- gtable_matrix("toprow", mat, unit(c(1, 0, 1), "null"), unit(c(1, 1), "null"))
```

The mask is created in two steps, covering the first facet group and then the second. In the first part, we are using the location we recorded earlier to grab the appropriate grob from the original plot and add it on top of our replacement matrix `res`, spanning the entire length. We then add that matrix on top of our plot.

```
# Adding the first layer
zz <- res %>%
  gtable_add_grob(z$grobs[[locations[1]]]$grobs[[1]], 1, 1, 1, 3) %>%
  gtable_add_grob(z, ., t = top,  l = l[1],  b = top,  r = r[1], name = c("add-strip"))

# Adding the second layer (note the indices)
pp <- gtable_add_grob(res, z$grobs[[locations[3]]]$grobs[[1]], 1, 1, 1, 3) %>%
  gtable_add_grob(zz, ., t = top,  l = l[2],  b = top,  r = r[2], name = c("add-strip"))

# Plotting
grid.newpage()
print(grid.draw(pp))
```

[image: Nested facet labels]

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. I've been struggling to work out how to generalise this solution to modify the facet labels if they occurred on the right of the plot. Could you show how one would modify your solution to suite the case where the layout was based on the plot function `ggplot(cbind(df,df), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(f1 + f2 ~ f3)`? I further need to generalise to a case with 12 facet rows reduced to 6 outer right labels rather than 4 and 2 (as the rewritten function I've provided would produce). Happy to provide a clear example if that helps. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi @nickb, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911134/2752888

Comment: Thanks for sharing a nice solution. For some reason I am failing to make it work when there are multiple rows in a facet_wrap(~id + id2, nrow = 4, ncol=8) setting. This is probably just me not fully understanding how I need to adapt your solution or overlooking something stupid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652308/combine-multiple-facet-strips-across-columns-in-ggplot2-facet-wrap (with minimum viable example & created plots).

Answer (score 80):

I'm sorry necroing this thread and unintended self-promotion, but I had a go at generalizing this to a `facet_nested()` function and it can be found in the ggh4x package.

The function isn't tested extensively but I thought it might be of some convenience to people. Maybe some good  feedback will come from this.

There are two other modifications that I made in this function beyond the scope of grouping strips. One is that it doesn't automatically expand missing variables. This is because I was of the opinion that nested facets should be able to co-exist with non-nested facets without any entries to the 2nd or further arguments in `vars()` when plotting with two data.frames. The second is that it orders the strips from outer to inner, so that inner is nearer to the panels than outer, even when `switch` is set.

Reproducing the plot in this question would then be as follows, assuming `df` is the `df` in the question above:

```r
# library(ggh4x)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_nested(f1 ~ f2 + f3)
```

[image]

There was also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0/40838827#40838827) with a more real-world example plot, which would work like the following, assuming `df` is the `df` from that question:

```r
p <- ggplot(df, aes("", density)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.7, position=position_dodge(0.7)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_nested(. ~ species + location +  position) +
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,"lines"),
        strip.background=element_rect(color="grey30", fill="grey90"),
        panel.border=element_rect(color="grey90"),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  labs(x="")
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this function can go to the ggforce package? It has lots of functionality about annotation, and it can be handy when color, shape are to encode other things.

Comment: I would think that it more belongs in the ggplot2 package itself since it relies on several internal ggplot2 functions.

Comment: I think ggplot maintains the philosophy that functions in the ggplot2 package should be 1. generally applicable and have low maintenance or 2. be an essential feature. Given that it is not been tested a lot (high maintenance) and isn't an essential feature, this would be best suited for an extension package.

Comment: facet_nested is definitely something I've been wanting for a long time; thanks for re-raising.  Features-wise, about the only thing to ask for is an additional theme-ing lever, to adjust the panel spacing by nesting.  Probably a nesting-depth multiplier is sufficient - I.e., if the spacing between panels at lowest level is 1, then one level up its 1.1, then two levels up 1.1^2, etc.

Comment: I can see what you mean and indeed that would be something that the theme settings would handle. Unfortunately I know very little about the themes so I wouldn't know where to start implementing this. It's always an option to set `theme(panel.spacing = unit(c(5,6,5), "points"))` manually when you have 1A 1B 2A 2B nesting, for example.

Comment: I get the following error 
`Error in do.call(unit.c, lapply(splitstrip, max_height)) : 
  object 'unit.c' not found ` 
with a simple example

`ggplot(mpg, aes(x= cty, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_nested(.~ manufacturer + model)`

Comment: Could you try `library(grid)` and/or `library(gtable)` and try again? This might be a bug on my part

Comment: Hi @teunbrand, do you know how to increase the space grey boxes in the upper part of the plot? I mean, the space for the facet labels. I am using `facet_nested` and I would like to change that for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @Dekike I answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029503/how-to-increase-space-among-different-boxes-created-for-the-facet-labels-using

Comment: @teunbrand: I like the result of your function very much - exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I get the error message "object '.int' " is missing. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: I think installing the package may help, the function is not standalone (anymore)

Comment: Was hard work getting the package - but it's done and it works. Great! Thanks

Comment: I love the idea behind this package.  Can you help me figure out how to install it? I always have these issues with dev tools, here was my error:

``** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in setClassUnion("knownContinuous", c("integer", "double", "numeric",  : 
  the member classes must be defined: not true of "double"
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘ggnomics’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggnomics’``

Comment: continued: ``* removing ‘../Library/R/3.5/library/ggnomics’
Error: Failed to install 'ggnomics' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/_4/k5fb7b_j5_q0hmn0_qx0l8900000gn/T//Rtmp2fKn9Q/file3a82cd5c03e/ggnomics_0.1.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status``

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor How did you end up at that package? I tried to link to the ggh4x package that now hosts this function instead of ggnomics, but apparently you were somehow led to the wrong package.

Comment: @teunbrand - is there a way to regulate number of columns? As you would with ```facet_wrap``` ```ncol``` argument? My plot is currently exactly what I want in terms of faceting, and completely illegible because of how many 'subplots' it has, all in one row.

Comment: There is a`facet_nested_wrap` function too in ggh4x. If that doesn't suit your needs, I'd need more details than that.