# ggplot2 / facet_wrap - shared labels for variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a problem i can't find a solution for.

I have a data set with 3 sample sites and different sample variables ("Bulk" and "Rhizosphere").

My code:

```
ggplot(data=dr_stats_all, aes(x=treatment, y=co2c, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ site  + type, nrow=1)
```

This gives me six subplots with the sample site labels twice for "Bulk" and "Rhizosphere".

Is there a way to share the lables from the sample sites?

[image: EXAMPLE IMAGE]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Reproducible questions provide a minimal amount of data so potential contributors can answer without having to spend time mocking up some data. the output of `dput(dr_stats_all)` in a code block would help folks help you. Having said that, it's very likely post-plot grob editing is what you're going to need to do to get close to what you want.

Comment: Related: [Nested facets in ggplot2 spanning groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316169/nested-facets-in-ggplot2-spanning-groups), and 'Linked' therein. Like @hrbrmstr said: massive grob digging.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to use only `site` to facet? You already use type to determine the fill, so adding a legend with the type (which is automatic) would suffice.

```
ggplot(data=dr_stats_all, aes(x=treatment, y=co2c, fill=type)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
facet_wrap(~ site, nrow=1)
```

If you really want to have nested facets, I also suggest taking a look at [Henrik's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316169/nested-facets-in-ggplot2-spanning-groups)

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this is, that i want to see the effects of different treatments, so nested facets would be better. 

I will check out Hendrik`s suggestion :)