# Draw market chart bar using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, financial

I need to draw market profile (aka volume profile) chart in R.

[image: volume chart example]

Above is an example of what I want. Horizontal axis is date. On the vertical axis I have level. And I also need to have horizontal bar at every date and every level that shows volume (bar to the right) and count (bar to the left).

My data looks like this. I have a date and level columns that I want to use for groups and volume and count to show as values.

```
   date                  level volume      count
1: 2019-03-04 00:00:00   0.4   50193087    51
2: 2019-03-04 00:00:00   0.1   30030902    50
3: 2019-03-04 00:00:00  -0.3   33674196    53
4: 2019-03-04 00:00:00   0.6   43566324    64
5: 2019-03-04 00:00:00  -0.5   74949678    66
6: 2019-03-04 00:00:00  -0.4   35799917    58
```

I don't even know where to start with that, it seems that I can't any existing chart types and even a combination. Stacked bar chart isn't going to work, because each bar's width needs to be adjusted according to volume/count. I was thinking about using population pyramid, but I'm not sure if I can use proper x axis (date) and also left bar would be almost invisible because right bar has much larger values and the share the same axis.

Does anybody know how I can draw this chart in r? Preferably using plotly or ggplot2.

**UPDATE**:
My data contains several dates, so chart actually should look like this

[image: example with multiple dates]

And here is new sample of data

```
date,level,volume,count
2019-03-04,0.4,50193087,51
2019-03-04,0.1,30030902,50
2019-03-04,-0.3,33674196,53
2019-03-04,0.6,43566324,64
2019-03-04,-0.5,74949678,66
2019-03-04,-0.4,35799917,58
2019-03-04,-0.1,99431328,46
2019-03-05,0.8,85373468,45
2019-03-05,0.5,76080717,51
2019-03-05,-0.7,45250685,48
2019-03-05,-0.9,47862662,48
2019-03-05,-0.2,43731758,48
2019-03-05,0.3,43375430,45
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a date on your x-axis and the volume/count (by means of bar width) also on the x-axis? I'm quite confident that you could map volume and count to x-axis, but not also with date.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is going to be my best guess at what is asked, though I'm not totally sure.

First I read in your data, which the poster can probably skip but may help others reproduce it:

```
zz <- "date,time,level,volume,count
2019-03-04,00:00:00,0.4,50193087,51
2019-03-04,00:00:00,0.1,30030902,50
2019-03-04,00:00:00,-0.3,33674196,53
2019-03-04,00:00:00,0.6,43566324,64
2019-03-04,00:00:00,-0.5,74949678,66
2019-03-04,00:00:00,-0.4,35799917,58"
df <- read.table(header = T, text = zz, sep = ",")
```

Then I copy your data to two seperate `data.frames`, giving each another facetting variable:

```
df1 <- df
df1$facet <- factor("count", levels = c("volume","count"))
df2 <- df
df2$facet <- factor("volume", levels = c("volume","count"))
```

And then we build the plot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(y = as.factor(level))) +
  # We have to call geom_tile twice since we work with two data.frames, y is inherited
  geom_tile(data = df1, 
            aes(x = 0.5 * count, width = count, height = 0.6, fill = level > 0)) +
  # The trick is to map the volume to negative values
  geom_tile(data = df2, 
            aes(x = -0.5 * volume, width = volume, height = 0.6, fill = level > 0)) +
  # Then we give some colours to the bars
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "limegreen", "FALSE" = "red")) +
  # Now we make sure the labelling is sensible on the x-axis, date is given as axis title.
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                     labels = function(x){ifelse(x < -1e6, paste0(abs(x)/1e6, "M"), x)},
                     name = df1$date[1]) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "level") +
  # Now we're making facets out of count/volume en set 'scales = "free_x"' 
  # to let them scale independently
  facet_grid(~ facet, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") +
  # Add a fake y-axis
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  # Fiddle around with themes
  # strip.placement and 'switch = "x"' above let volume/count labels take place of x-axis
  # Panel spacing is set to zero to let the facets appear as if it were one
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

And the result:

[image]

Is that anywhere near what you had in mind?

EDIT: A solution for multiple dates (sort of) on the x-axis. First I refactored the data to get more dates in there:

```
# df from previous example
df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("date","level", "time"))
df2 <- cbind(date = "2019-03-05", df[,-1])
df3 <- cbind(date = "2019-03-06", df[,-1])

df <- rbind(df, df2, df3)
```

Next, it's going to look a lot like the previous plot with an addition of a `geom_blank()` that ensures every volume/count has the same x-axis range and using date as a facetting variable.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_tile(data = df[df$variable == "count",],
            aes(y = as.factor(level), x = 0.5 * value, width = value, fill = level > 0), 
            height = 2/(1 + sqrt(5))) +
  geom_tile(data = df[df$variable == "volume",],
            aes(y = as.factor(level), x = -0.5 * value, width = value, fill = level > 0), 
            height = 2/(1 + sqrt(5))) +
  # This controls x scale range to get uniform x-axis between dates
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = c(-max(df$value[df$variable == "volume"]),
                                      max(df$value[df$variable == "count"])), 
                               y = 0, variable = c("volume", "count")),
             aes(x = x * 1.1, y = y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  # Drop the name
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0,0,0),
                     labels = function(x){abs(x)},
                     name = "") +
  # Now facet over data and variable
  facet_grid(~ date + variable, switch = "x", scales = "free_x") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        # You can also set all spacing to unit(0,"mm") for a continuous look.
        panel.spacing.x = unit(rep_len(c(0, 5.5), 2*nlevels(df$date) - 1), "pt"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

You'll notice that the dates aren't particularly well-placed and we can't switch them in our code with the variable otherwise it will be grouped by count/volume instead of by date. Also there is no easy way to de-duplicate the dates. In my defence, mapping 3 vastly different variables to the same axis is a bit overkill. But, if you really want the date labels to look pretty, I suggest you have a look at this question: [Nested facets in ggplot2 spanning groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316169/nested-facets-in-ggplot2-spanning-groups), or edit them outside R with an image editing program.

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like I want. Thank you very much. However, I found one problem with your solution. You assumed that there is only one date, but there are a range of dates. I'm sorry that I didn't clarify this in the description. I updated example in the description. I think I need to draw a second x axis with dates. Or maybe there is another solution.