# ggplot: Cover `facet_grid` title with rectangle

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

This is an extension/hack to a similar question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822398/ggplot-centralize-facet-grid-title-and-appear-only-once).

I Created a graph in `ggplot` and I want to cover the titles of a `facet_grid` with a rectangle.

Using `geom_rect` I manged to spread rectangles over each facet. However, how can I spread the  rectangles over the titles?

Current graph: 
[image]

Expected graph:

[image]

Sample data and script:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- head(mtcars, 5)

plot <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, disp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~am + carb,
             space = "free_x", 
             scales = "free_x") +
  ggplot2::theme(
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"), 
    axis.ticks.length=unit(.25, "cm"), 
    strip.placement = "outside",
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key.size = ggplot2::unit(1.5, "lines"),
    # switch off the rectangle around symbols
    legend.key = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.key.width = grid::unit(2, "lines"),
    # # facet titles
    strip.background = ggplot2::element_rect(
      colour = "black",
      fill = "white"),
    panel.background = ggplot2::element_rect(
      colour = "white",
      fill = "white"), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

plot + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=2.4, xmax=2.7, ymin=400, ymax=300),
            color="black", fill="white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2.5, y = 400, label="world"), size=2)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you manually draw in Word/PPT/Paint what the expected output is?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126171/create-border-and-title-for-each-column-in-facet-wrap

Comment: I guess the easiest would be create each plot stand alone, and combine with patchwork.

Comment: I was only now, after all this hack, suddenly remembering the `ggnomics` package. check out my second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832084/7941188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the related post, one can now easily created nested facets with the `ggnomics` package, available on GitHub.

This does not *quite* exactly what you were asking here (annotating outside the plot area with rectangles that go across facets) but probably achieves what you want in the end... 
Annotating across facets would require another grob hack...

```r
#devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggnomics")
  library(ggnomics)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
  library(tidyverse)

  mydat<- head(mtcars, 5)
  mydat %>% 
    ggplot(aes(gear, disp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_nested(~am + carb) +
    theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"), 
          axis.ticks.length=unit(.25, "cm"), 
          strip.placement = "inside",
          strip.background = element_rect( colour = "black", fill = "white"),
          panel.background = element_rect( colour = "black", fill = "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>