# How to not repeat facet_grid names when using multiple levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am using a facet_grid with two row levels: family and Reach (see figure).
The name of the family is repeated twice, is there a way to have the family level only show once, and for it to encompass both reaches (the other group)?

[image: Face grid with one of the names being repeated]

My code:

```
ggplot(bubbleplot2, aes(x = week, y = year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = x ),fill="grey", alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) + 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0,10)) + 
  labs( x= "Date", y = "", size = "Catch")  + 
  theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold", angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 9), 
       # legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face ="bold", colour ="black"), 
       # legend.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"), panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2), 
        legend.position = "none", panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey95")) +  
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(bubbleplot2$year)))+
  facet_grid( family + Reach ~ .)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911134/2461552)?  It shows how to nest facet strips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested facets in ggplot2 spanning groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316169/nested-facets-in-ggplot2-spanning-groups)