# How to format ggplot points with nested facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-point

I have a dataset where I analysed SNPs, INDELs and SVs with two different tools `DeepVariant` and `PanGenie`. Now, `DeepVariant` only assesses SNPs and INDELs, whereas `PanGenie` is more tailor-suited for SVs. So, when I plot a comparison between the two tools I'm using against two different graph assemblies this is what I get
[image]
What I would like instead, it is a plot where both the SNPs and INDELs as well as the SVs facets stretch the entire length of the figure. I don't mind to use nested facets with `DeepVariant`and `PanGenie` on the left side of the plot over the type of variants they assess, respectively.
I've seen some similar examples but they have the same child facets within the parent one (*see* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652308/combine-multiple-facet-strips-across-columns-in-ggplot2-facet-wrap)).

Below, the code I used

```
library(grid)
library(ggh4x)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggdark)
library(ggpubr)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)
library(ggchicklet) #round column
library(RColorBrewer)

excel <- read_excel("/media/mat/Extreme SSD/TheUniversityOfFerrara/3°Year/pangenie_giraffe-dv_orth_val.xlsx") # load spreadsheet

df <- data.frame(excel) # convert excel to dataframe

df$variant_type <- factor(df$variant_type, levels=c('SNPs', 'INDELs', 'SVs')) # order of variants to be displayed
df$metric <- factor(df$metric, levels=c('recall', 'precision', 'F1')) # order of metrics to be shown

df_2 <- with(df, df[order(variant_type, caller, graph, metric),]) # collapses fields with the same entry

### Personalized stripes
ridiculous_strips <- strip_themed(
  ## Horizontal strips
  background_x = elem_list_rect(fill=c("#f9ab00", "#ffaaaa")),
  text_x = elem_list_text(colour=c("black", "black"), face=c("bold", "bold")),
  by_layer_x = FALSE,
  
  ## Vertical strips
  background_y = elem_list_rect(fill = c("slategray3", "slategray3", "slategray3")),
  by_layer_y = FALSE
)

### PLOT orthogonal validation of variants callers and graphs used
variants_eval <- ggplot(df_2, aes(x=metric, y=value, fill=graph)) + geom_point(shape=21, alpha=.6, size=3)
ggplot(df_2, aes(x=metric, y=value, fill=graph)) + geom_point(shape=21, alpha=.6, size=3) +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(variant_type ~ caller, scales='free', switch='y', independent='y', strip=ridiculous_strips) + scale_fill_manual(values=rev(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")[c(1, 11)])) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='assembly', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5, title.theme=element_text(face='italic'))) + ggtitle("variant_calling — effect of alignment tool and graph used") +
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.position='bottom') -> callers_graphs
callers_graphs
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I don't understand the desired outcome despite what I believe must be an accurate description. Would you care adding a sketch of how you would want it to look like? And maybe, maybe create a fake data set, or use one of R's many many data sets to make this probably interesting question more reproducible?

Comment: @tjebo I provided a simple drawing of what I intend to do and also a possible solution. However, as you can see, I'm not able to get both personalised stripes as well as the nested facets around them. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: As you're already using ggh4x, you can use `strip_nested()` instead of `strip_themed()`.

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand I did exactly that and switched to `facet_nested_wrap()` to get both SNPs and INDELs under the `DeepVariant` strip!