# How do you add a general label to facets in ggplot2 3.3.0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to add general labels to facets in ggplot2. My code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x= 1:100, y= 1:100,
                 sport= rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each= 50),
                 female= rep(c(TRUE, FALSE)))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(female ~ sport)
```

And the plot I get is:

[image: plot]

As you can see the labels are not informative at all. How can I add general lebals in facets? Here, it is `sport` and `female`.

There is already a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353287/how-do-you-add-a-general-label-to-facets-in-ggplot2) but the answer does not work with the current ggplot2 3.3.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [labeller](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html) argument. For your example, manual values will work, but probably assigning functions scales better for your real usecase.

Here is an example of both:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x= 1:100, y= 1:100,
                 sport= rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each= 50),
                 female= rep(c(TRUE, FALSE)))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point()

# Using manual values
p1 +
  facet_grid(
    female ~ sport,
    labeller = labeller(
      female = c("TRUE" = "A", "FALSE" = "B"),
      sport = c("TRUE" = "C", "FALSE" = "D")
    )
  )
```

[image]

```r
# Using functions
your_labeller <- labeller(
  female = stringr::str_to_lower,
  sport = stringr::str_to_title
)

p1 +
  facet_grid(
    female ~ sport,
    labeller = your_labeller
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I ended up using `p1 + facet_grid(female ~ sport, labeller = labeller(.rows = label_both, .cols = label_both))` which is almoust as I expected..